# Скрип древних шестеренок, ржавых от подозрительности

Tags: орфография, лексика, грамматика, переводы, идиомы

Читаю книгу Рэя Брэдбери - 451 градус по Фаренгейту в переводе Виталия Бабенко. Есть там следующий текст:

```
Гончая приподнялась в конуре и уставилась на него внезапно 
включившимися лампамиглазами, в которых замерцал сине-зеленый 
неоновый свет. Она снова взрыкнула – ее рык был странной, режущей 
ухо смесью электрического шипения, потрескивания масла на 
раскаленной сковороде, скрежета металла и скрипа древних 
шестеренок, ржавых от подозрительности.
```

И я все в толк не возьму, что означает эта фраза `ржавых от подозрительности`? Есть ощущение что это либо какая-то опечатка, либо переводчик просто не придумал ничего лучше и оставил как есть `"И так сойдет"`

С другой стороны, в оригинале:

```
The Hound half rose in its kennel and looked at him with green-blue neon
light flickering in its suddenly activated eye bulbs. It growled again, a strange
rasping combination of electrical sizzle, a frying sound, a scraping of metal, a
turning of cogs that seemed rusty and ancient with suspicion.
```

это выглядит так же непонятно, а именно `rusty and ancient with suspicion`.

Момент я этот уже давно пролистал и читаю дальше, но все время вспоминаю и хочу понять. Как вообще "ржавый" и "от подозрительности", что в переводе, что в общем-то в оригинале, могут быть связаны в одно.

Comment: Их подозрительность ржавчиной гложет.   https://infopedia.su/20x2764.html

Comment: Подозрительность — плохое чувство и для людей, и для шестеренок. Они от этого ржавеют. Метафорический оборот.

Comment: "Ржавых от подозрительности" - на русском означает "ржавых от частых проявлений подозрительности", но думаю этот перевод - ошибка. Какой перевод правильный? Лучше задать этот вопрос преподам по английскому. Наверное, что-то типа "ржавых с подозрением", но так не говорят.

Comment: В другом переводе. Давно заброшенный механизм, скрипучий от ржавчины и стариковской подозрительности.

Comment: The Hound half rose in its kennel and looked at him with green-blue neon light flickering in its suddenly activated **eyebulbs**

Comment: Рэй Брэдбери. 451 градус по Фаренгейту
Перевод Т. Шинкарь Изд: Рэй Брэдбери "О скитаниях вечных и о Земле". Изд. "Правда", 1987. "..словно пришел в движение какой-то ветхий, давно заброшенный механизм, скрипучий от ржавчины и стариковской подозрительности."

Answer (score 0):

А лампамиглазами не смутило? Дефис, однако, нужен.

Пошла в Гугл-переводчик, а он и говорит:

> Пес наполовину приподнялся в своей конуре и посмотрел на него
> зелено-голубым неоновым светом. Свет мерцал в внезапно активированных
> глазных лампочках. Он снова зарычал - странная грубая комбинация
> электрического шипения, звука жарки, скрежета металла, будто с
> подозрением поворачивались винтики, которые казались ржавыми и
> древними.

Я только чуток согласование подправила.

Но конечно же, "и так сойдёт" не подразумевалось: переводчик несёт рукопись редактору - куда ж без него? Захочет - оставит, захочет - изменит; мне переводчица жаловалась на форточку, которая хлопала в сердце героя, - при буквальном переводе.

Вот [другой перевод](https://biblioteka-online.info/book/451-gradus-po-farengeytu/reader/6/) означенного отрывка:

> Механический пес спал и в то же время бодрствовал; жил и в то же время
> был мертв в своей мягко гудящей, мягко вибрирующей, слабо освещенной
> конуре в конце темного коридора пожарной станции. Бледный свет ночного
> неба проникал через большое квадратное окно, и блики играли то тут, то
> там на медных, бронзовых и стальных частях механического зверя. Свет
> отражался в кусочках рубинового стекла, слабо переливался и мерцал на
> тончайших, как капилляры, чувствительных нейлоновых волосках в ноздрях
> этого странного чудовища, чуть заметно вздрагивающего на своих восьми
> паучьих, подбитых резиной лапах.

Comment: Другой перевод отрывка, по ссылке, чуть дальше: `Пес приподнялся в конуре и взглянул на Монтэга внезапно ожившими, полными зелено-синих неоновых искр глазами. Снова он заворчал — странный, режущий ухо звук, смесь электрического жужжания, шипения масла на сковороде и металлического скрежета, словно пришел в движение какой-то ветхий механизм, скрипучий от ржавчины и застарелой подозрительности.`

Comment: Я бы предложил: ... смесь щелчков от серии электроразрядов, ворчания масла на сковороде, скрежета металлических шестерёнок, изношенных ржавчиной, годами и всегдашней настороженностью.

Comment: Вот и я о том же. Всё в руках редактора - может и консилиум созвать.